# lightweight-charts - How to setup a chart background collor to black?

Tags: javascript, lightweight-charts

I am using the [[lightweight-charts]](https://www.tradingview.com/lightweight-charts/) javascript library to generate some charts. For this example I am using the [Realtime emulation chart](https://jsfiddle.net/TradingView/yozeu6k1/).

In this example the background color is white. I would like to set the background color to black. I am following the documentation but I can't achieve the goal.

Following is the code I am using but it is not working:

```
var chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    background: '#000000',
    textColor: '#ffffff'
});


var candleSeries = chart.addCandlestickSeries();
var data = [...]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to wrap both background & textColor within a `layout` property like

```
var chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
  width: 1200,
  height: 800,
  layout: {
    background: {
      color: '#000000'
    },
    textColor: '#ffffff'
  }
});
```

as seen in this [doc](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/next/migrations/from-v3-to-v4)

Comment: hi, it worked. Where did you find in the documentation that we should use with a `layout` onject?

Comment: In case you didn't notice we've launched a new [website](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/) for lightweight charts and from there you can search any part of the documentation.